# Perl - format output and read formatted data

Tags: perl, csv, format

I'm trying to write some data into CSV files and also read back those data. For better readability, I have used Perl format to create a table-like appearance, and for the data to be displayed in proper columns when opened in Excel, I have used commas to separate the columns. My table is a list of IDs with its respective attributes. Below is the format I am using to display each ID:

```
format TABLE = 
@<<<<<, ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<, ^<<<<, @<<<<, @<<<<<
$ID,   $description,    $att,  $errors, $location
      , ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<, ^<<<<,
       $description,    $att
      , ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<, ^<<<<,
       $description,    $att
      , ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      $description
      , ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      $description
.
```

The problem I am having with this format is that the number of lines reserved to display `$description` and `$att` is fixed. If my string is longer than that it would be truncated and if shorter than 5 lines there will always be empty lines being displayed. Since the length of the `$description` string is not predictable, is there any way to make sure the content would be fully displayed even if it's longer and without trailing empty lines even if it's shorter than the number of specified lines in the format?

Current output:

```
13_456, this is a examp, val1:, 3    , fold1
      , le of a line th, x; va,
      , at if follow th, l2: y,
      , e current forma,
      , t would be trun,

12_456, this is a short, val1:, 0    , fold2
      ,  description   , a; va,
      ,                , l2: b,
      ,                ,
      ,                ,
```

Desired output:

```
13_456, this is a examp, val1:, 3    , fold1
      , le of a line th, x; va,
      , at if follow th, l2: y,
      , e current forma,
      , t would be trun,
      , cated          ,

12_456, this is a short, val1:, 0    , fold2
      ,  description   , a; va,
      ,                , l2: b,
```

For reading from file, I am able to parse the file line by line to match the `$ID` pattern and retrieve all the information for that ID (`$description`, `$att`, `$errors`, `$location`). But since I am printing out data using Perl format, I'm just wondering if I can make use of this format to read back the data, ie does Perl provide any library/functionality that helps read data that fits a specified Perl format? I have done some research but have not seemed to find one, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some example input and output? I'd usually suggest looking at say, `sprintf` if you've more complex formatting requirements.

Comment: I have put in examples of current and desired outputs. I don't really need complex formatting, just looking for probably a more flexible way of formatting the output such that I can display data fully and without trailing empty lines.

Comment: Perl's `format` system is very rarely used, and I recommend that you go to the [Perl6::Form](http://metacpan.org/module/Perl6::Form) module, which is a backwards port of the Perl 6 form system to Perl 5 and does things "properly". I don't know whether it does what you're asking for, which is why this is a comment and not a solution, but I'll take a look shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's around five years since I last looked at `format`, but I think what you need is the auto-repeat flag `~~` which indicates that a format line should be re-used until the variables have been emptied

You've made it very difficult to write something that works, as you've given us no data, and the format statement you show can't have produced that output because the field widths are different. You must also have messed with `$:` (`$FORMAT_LINE_BREAK_CHARACTERS`) to get your output split like that but you don't mention it

Here's some code that generates what you asked for except for limiting the number of rows of output. You can't do a multi-line auto-fill as well as limiting the number of lines, and it seems that you will need to use `substr` to limit the length of `$description` if it exceeds 75 characters (5 lines of 15 characters)

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ( $ID, $description, $att, $errors, $location );

format STDOUT =
@<<<<<, ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<, ^<<<<, @<<<<, @<<<<<
$ID,   $description,    $att,  $errors, $location
      , ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<, ^<<<<, ~~
       $description,    $att

.

local $:;

( $ID, $description, $att, $errors, $location ) = (
    '13_456',
    'this is a example of a line that if follow the current format would be truncated at the end of the fifth line',
    'val1:x; va12: y',
    3,
    'fold1',
);

write STDOUT;

( $ID, $description, $att, $errors, $location ) = (
    '12_456',
    'this is a shortdescription',
    'val1:a; val2: b',
    3, 'fold2',
);

write STDOUT;
```

#### output

```
13_456, this is a examp, val1:, 3    , fold1
      , le of a line th, x; va,
      , at if follow th, 12: y,
      , e current forma,      ,
      , t would be trun,      ,
      , cated at the en,      ,
      , d of the fifth ,      ,
      , line           ,      ,

12_456, this is a short, val1:, 3    , fold2
      , description    , a; va,
      ,                , l2: b,
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, this is exactly what I am looking for! As I cannot post my actual data here, the outputs I put in my question was made up and formatted by hand just for illustration purpose, really sorry if that caused any inconvenience to you, I will take note of that! And thanks again for your answer!

Comment: I realise that it may be impossible to publish confidential data. But you have created some sample data that you could have shown together with your code. I had to work backwards from your output data to create what I think your input looks like, but I can't see any way to get Perl to split `this is a short description` without putting the space between `short` and `description` somewhere. I have done it by using `this is a shortdescription` instead, and setting `$:` to `undef`, but it is a shame when it takes longer to recreate the problem than it does to resolve it

Comment: Ok noted, thanks a lot! I will take your advice for future questions!

Answer (score -2):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel, use a module that's specialized for the task at hand: [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV).

Comment: Might the downvoters please be so kind to explain why they downvoted this?